# How to remove the black stroke of legend bars when [draw=none] was used for plotting the bars

Tags: pgfplots

I made the bars with `[draw=none]` but inside legend the bars have a black stroke around them. Why isn't the style preserved? How could I remove the black stroke of the legend bars?

```
\addplot[draw=none, fill=green] table[x=p, y=dmsqr] {gfx/my_data.dat};
```

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[xbar] 
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=blue] coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \addlegendentry{Blue} 
        \addplot [draw=none, fill=red] coordinates {(3,5) (5,10) (15,15) (20,20) (35,25)}; 
        \addlegendentry{Red}
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It could be a bug, or it could be an old version.  If you gave an MWE I would test it myself.

Comment: It looks indeed like a bug. Try adding `legend image post style={draw opacity=0}` to your axis options.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I added an MWE. Well, I found a workaround... If I do `[draw=green, fill=green]` then it works.

Comment: @percusse Your suggestion works!

Comment: For the record: I think this could be related to the [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/64/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: @StefanPinnow How can the question be off-topic? It's about pgfplots.

Comment: @remus, the "off-topic" is a default text of one options when closing a question. The reason for closing the question is, that - as I have stated in the comment related to the close vote - it is solved in the comments (as you have stated yourself).
Because you have found a bug (which - as I also already have written in a comment - is already reported in the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/64/) there will most probably no "real" answer which can be accepted. So this question will remain as "not accepted".